# Wrap UITextView text to corner radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, calayer

How to wrap the text of UITextView to its corner radius ? Currently when i apply corner radius to the UITextView the corner text gets cut. I want to wrap the text to circular. I cannot use UIWebView instead of UITextView. Does anybody have solution for this ? I cannot use core text since i have multiple textviews so it will be very complicated. Is there a way to use CALayer for this ?

Comment: Add UIView with corner radius and over that view add your UITextView. Hope it will help you.

Comment: you can add some space on left and right side of textview.

Comment: `[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)];`